# Reading IIS Session Variables from Flask App with wfastcgi.py

Tags: python, flask, session, iis, iis-7

I'm building a secured app with Flask 0.12 on IIS 7.0. The site is on a subdomain so its urls all begin with:

```
https://<subdomain>.<domain>/<app_name>/
```

`wfastcgi.py` strips away these prefixes and passes only the route names to my Flask app. So the above URL would be presented to my app as route `/`. There are other web apps (ASP.net and PHP) hosted on the same subdomain but with different `app_name` constants.

Since my users are required to login to the server before hitting my app, I'd like to use their Windows domain unique user ids to manage page-by-page permissions in the app. In ASP.NET I could do this using the `httpcontext` but that isn't available in Flask. And when I dump the session contents like so:

```
@app.route('/session_tester')
def session_test():
    return str(session)
```

I get an empty page in response.

How can I access my IIS session variables from the Flask App? Is there a configuration variable I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user is authenticated by IIS, their username is present in the `REMOTE_USER` environment variable. Other contextual information is also stored in different environment variables. You can configure which variables are made available to the application, but `REMOTE_USER` and a few others should be there by default.

So, you should be able to get the logged in user by `os.environ.get('REMOTE_USER')`.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    username = os.environ.get('REMOTE_USER')
    template = "<h1>User: {{ username }}</h1>"
    return render_template_string(template, username=username)
```

If you want your Flask session to be aware of the user session, you need to have users log into the Flask app, not IIS. Alternatively, you can have a middleware that logs users into your Flask app based on the `REMOTE_USER` environment variable. This should be achievable using the `flask_login` extension, for example.

Edit:

You can also access environment variables via the `request` proxy object. e.g. `request.environ['REMOTE_USER']`. See also [request.authorization](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/)

Comment: This didn't work. I dumped the entire contents of os.environ and 'REMOTE-USER' isn't there.

Comment: I did some further research. Turns out that 'REMOTE-USER' is not stored in os.environ but as part of the WSGI spec, it is passed to my Flask object upon initialization. I can access it with the statement request.environ['REMOTE-USER']. If you can edit your response to include this I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Note that it's an underscore, not a dash. IE `REMOTE_USER` not `REMOTE-USER`. It probably works with `request.environ` because  Werkzeug makes keys insensitive to case and dashes/underscores, IIRC. Let me know. I'll edit the answer anyhow though.